# Split string using Regular Expression that includes lowercase, camelcase, numbers

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on to get twitter trends using tweepy in python and I'm able find out world top 50 trends so for sample I'm getting results like these

```
#BrazilianFansAreTheBest, #PSYPagtuklas, Federer, Corcuera, Ouvindo ANTI,
艦これ改, 영혼의 나이, #TodoDiaéDiaDe, #TronoChicas, #이사람은_분위기상_군주_장수_책사, 
#OTWOLKnowYourLimits, #BaeIn3Words, #NoEntiendoPorque
```

(Please ignore non English words)

So here I need to parse every hashtag and convert them into proper English words, Also I checked how people write hashtag and found below ways -

```
 #thisisawesome
 #ThisIsAwesome
 #thisIsAwesome 
 #ThisIsAWESOME
 #ThisISAwesome
 #ThisisAwesome123
```

(some time hashtags have numbers as well)

So keeping all these in mind I thought if I'm able to split below string then all above cases will be covered.

---

```
string ="pleaseHelpMeSPLITThisString8989"

Result = please, Help, Me, SPLIT, This, String, 8989
```

I tried something using `re.sub` but it is not giving me desired results.

Comment: How you differentiate between `"SPLITT", "his"` and `"SPLIT", "This"`?

Comment: there is no way to split that string using regular expressions. you need to use Natural Language processing. Like running the the string against a dictionary of words

Comment: Note that your vague description falls well short of a [mcve].

Comment: Try [`(?<=[A-Z]{2})(?=[A-Z0-9][a-z0-9])|(?:(?<=[a-z]))(?=[A-Z0-9])`](https://regex101.com/r/jW3hA9/1) and then split. But seriously, this is only matching this example of yours, there is no guarantee that it will work with the rest.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Yes, this is the problem I'm facing.

Comment: @Sanchit is there a must to use regex here? Offered example is weird and hard to read. Such problems can be more easily solved by char-by-char parsing

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Sorry about the bas description, I'll edit it to make it as per guidelines.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doesn't work for `123iSUFFERSoHard` :(

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: Let me edit this question and that may help you understand my problem better.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: Sure it won't. The strings could be split with a regex if there was only one problem, but there are two: ALLCAPS words and CaMeL words.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I believe it is okay but there is no option to lookbehind numbers

Answer (score 0):

**Regex is the wrong tool for the job.** You need a clearly-defined pattern in order to write a good regex, and in this case, you don't have one. Given that you can have `Capitalized Words`, `CAPITAL WORDS`, `lowercase words`, and numbers, there's no real way to look at, say, `THATSand` and differentiate between `THATS and` or `THAT Sand`.

A natural-language approach would be a better solution, but again, it's inevitably going to run into the same problem as above - how do you differentiate between two (or more) perfectly valid ways to parse the same inputs? Now you'd need to get a trie of common sentences, build one for each language you plan to parse, and *still* need to worry about properly parsing the nonsensical tags twitter often comes up with.

The question becomes, why do you need to split the string at all? I would recommend finding a way to omit this requirement, because it's almost certainly going to be easier to change the problem than it is to develop this particular solution.